# Where was this picture taken? (Chromecast background, 3 steep rocks)

Tags: identify-this, photography, locate-this, remote-locations

Can anybody say where this Chromecast background was taken? Google reverse image search is not helping unfortunately.

A few more keywords:

- Tree-covered three-top-mountain.
- Orange clouds.

[image: The photo]

Comment: FYI [this site](https://chromecastbg.alexmeub.com/) has tons of the Chromecast backgrounds in various resolutions.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

A TinEye reverse image search of this image shows one hit with the filename
`huangshan_mountains-other.jpg`.

Huangshan is a mountain range in Southern Anhui Province in Eastern China. I can't find any other images of this particular rock formation but the general geography of the area definitely looks similar.

Comment: The photo resembles a style of Chinese scroll painting. I used to think the paintings were artistic exaggeration until I visited China.

Comment: It was relatively easy to find other pictures of the same triple peak, so it is indeed in Huangshan. I find no reference however to its exact location, except that it is supposed to be somewhere in the West Sea Grand Canyon: https://www.chinadiscovery.com/huangshan-tours/how-to-plan-mount-huangshan-tour.html

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan TBH, I thought it was a screen grab from a video game like _Myst_ or something similar...

Answer (score 29):

That would appear to be the Huangshan mountains in China. See [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RPBT7ztASiU&t=108) at 1:48.

[image: Huangshan Mountains]

Comment: The accepted answer already identifies this as the Huangshan mountains.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas but the accepted answer also says *"I can't find any other images of this particular rock formation but the general geography of the area definitely looks similar."* - so I thought I'd provide an answer with some evidence.

Comment: @abligh It might enhance your answer to include a still of the video at that timestamp. Links, in any case, are very prone to "rot", so including details within the answer is generally preferred.

Comment: It looks like this is the video from which the crops in William's answer were taken.

Comment: Thanks for this great and perfect answer, which should be the accepted answer.